# Loop through csv and pull from web

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I could use some help. I am stuck. I want to read a .csv ("IMDb_id.csv"), it has one column (Imdb_link) that contains random IMDb tile URLs. I want it to iterate through the rows grab the URL and then scrape the URL for the title, image, genre, actor and director. I then want to download the image, save it with the name of the IMDb title and put the actor and director in one.csv. This code right now works and brings down one poster, puts the actor and director in its own .csv but doesn't iterate through the .csv or combine into one .csv.

```
print("Current Working Directory " , os.getcwd())
os.chdir('/Users/Desktop/PROJECT MOVIE ANALITICA')

df_IMDb_id_URL = pd.read_csv("IMDb_id.csv")
#print(df_IMDb_id_URL.head(3))


#df_IMDb_id =[]
for column,row in df_IMDb_id_URL.iteritems():
    #print(index)
    Movie_URL = row
    print(Movie_URL)


r = requests.get('https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0037800')
r_unparsed = r.text
start = time.time()
Movie_IMDb_Page = BeautifulSoup(r_unparsed,'lxml')
end = time.time()

for index in Movie_IMDb_Page.find_all("script",type="application/ld+json"):
        result_dictionary = json.loads(index.contents[0])
Image_URL = result_dictionary['image']

Movie_ID = result_dictionary['url']
Image_ID_Name = re.sub('/|title', '', Movie_ID)
title = Movie_IMDb_Page.title.text
description = Movie_IMDb_Page.find('div','summary_text').text.strip()


url_response = urllib.request.urlopen(Image_URL)
print(url_response)

# Python Requests Tutorial- Request Web Pages, Download Images, POST Data, Read JSON, and More.mp4
print(Image_URL) #Print URL

Image_URL_request = requests.get(Image_URL)

try:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "POSTER"))
except:
    pass

os.chdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "POSTER"))


with open(Image_ID_Name + '.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(Image_URL_request.content)


Actors_List =[]
Directors_List =[]
Creators_List =[]
Genre_List =[]


Movie_ID = result_dictionary['url']
Actors = result_dictionary['actor']
Directors = result_dictionary['director']
Creators = result_dictionary['creator']
Genres = result_dictionary['genre']

print(re.sub('/|title', '', Movie_ID))

print (Movie_ID)
#print (res_str_ID)

#print (Actors)
for index in Actors:
        Actors_List.append(str(index[u'name'])) 

for index in Directors:
        Directors_List.append(str(index[u'name']))

#for index in Creators:
#        Creators_List.append(str(index[u'name']))

#Method PANDAS
df = pd.DataFrame(Actors_List)
#df.to_csv('Actors_List.csv')
df.to_csv('Actors_List.csv', index=False, header=False) # removes the headers from csv and saves

#Method PANDAS
df = pd.DataFrame(Directors_List)
#df.to_csv('Actors_List.csv')
df.to_csv('Directors_List.csv', index=False, header=False) # removes the headers from csv and saves

print(result_dictionary['contentRating'])
print(Genres)
print(Actors_List)
print(Directors_List)
print(Creators)
```

Comment: this is hardcoded url r = requests.get('https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0037800') Shouldn't it be the MovieUrl? then that line and everything can indent under the for loop????

Comment: @Jonathan Leon- yes, that is what I was originally having a hard time wrapping my brain around on how to call it. I'm still very new at Python. I used what you suggested and that definitely was one of my issues that was hanging me. up.